# Method @Produces return null when is inject

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cdi, ejb-3.0, resteasy

I have a problem with my method @Produces. 
When I inject `ResteasyWebTarget` target in my Api Request class, object target is null.

Can someone help me with this. CDI not working in my class...

```
    @Qualifier
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @Target({TYPE, METHOD, PARAMETER, FIELD})
    public @interface ServiceProducer {

    }
```

```
public class ServiceProducerImpl implements Serializable {

    @Produces
    @ServiceProducer
    public ResteasyWebTarget getClient() {
        String patApi = "http://localhost:5000";
        try {
            ResteasyClient client = new ResteasyClientBuilder().build();
            ResteasyWebTarget target = client.target(UriBuilder.fromPath(patApi));
            return target;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

```
  @Path("/api-java")
  public interface IServices {

      @PUT
      @Path("/put")
      @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
      @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
      Response putservice(ApiRequestModel api);
  }
```

```
public class ApiRequest {

    @Inject
    @ServiceProducer
    ResteasyWebTarget target;

    public void rest() {
        String patApi = "http://localhost:5000";
        try {

            IServices service = target.proxy(IServices.class);
            ApiRequestModel api = new ApiRequestModel(11, "22", 0);
            Response response = service.putservice(api);
            ApiResponseModel apiResponse = response.readEntity(ApiResponseModel.class);
            System.out.println("API-JAVA>> " + "CNPJ: " + apiResponse.getCnpj() + " ADQ: " + apiResponse.getAdq() + " BLOCKCODE: " + apiResponse.getBlockcode());

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: If it returns null it also prints a stacktrace? Or is tge injection just not working (@inject annotation not parsed) and consequently the producer not called at all. I suspect the latter since I cannot see any annotation or  cpnfiguration that would make `ApiRequest` eligeable for injection.

Comment: can you show us the content of your beans.xml?

Comment: <beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd">
</beans>

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Model Class

```
public class ApiRequestModel {

    private int adq;


    private String cnpj;


    private int blockcode;

    public ApiRequestModel(int adq, String cnpj, int blockcode) {
        this.adq = adq;
        this.cnpj = cnpj;
        this.blockcode = blockcode;
    }

    public int getAdq() {
        return adq;
    }

    public void setAdq(int adq) {
        this.adq = adq;
    }

    public String getCnpj() {
        return cnpj;
    }

    public void setCnpj(String cnpj) {
        this.cnpj = cnpj;
    }

    public int getBlockcode() {
        return blockcode;
    }

    public void setBlockcode(int blockcode) {
        this.blockcode = blockcode;
    }
}

public class ApiResponseModel {


    private int adq;


    private String cnpj;


    private int blockcode;

    public ApiResponseModel( @JsonProperty("adq") int adq,  @JsonProperty("cnpj") String cnpj, @JsonProperty("blockcode") int blockcode) {
        this.adq = adq;
        this.cnpj = cnpj;
        this.blockcode = blockcode;
    }

    public int getAdq() {
        return adq;
    }

    public void setAdq(int adq) {
        this.adq = adq;
    }

    public String getCnpj() {
        return cnpj;
    }

    public void setCnpj(String cnpj) {
        this.cnpj = cnpj;
    }

    public int getBlockcode() {
        return blockcode;
    }

    public void setBlockcode(int blockcode) {
        this.blockcode = blockcode;
    }
}
```

Produces

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({TYPE, METHOD, PARAMETER, FIELD})
public @interface ServiceProducer {

}

public class ServiceProducerImpl {

    @Produces
    @ServiceProducer
    public ResteasyWebTarget getClient() {
        String patApi = "http://localhost:5000";
        try {
            ResteasyClient client = new ResteasyClientBuilder().build();
            ResteasyWebTarget target = client.target(UriBuilder.fromPath(patApi));
            return target;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Services interface

```
@Path("/api-java")
public interface IServices {

    @PUT
    @Path("/put")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    Response putservice(ApiRequestModel api);
}
```

How inject Produces

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class ApiRequest {

    @Inject
    @ServiceProducer
    private ResteasyWebTarget target;

    public void rest() {
        try {
            IServices service = target.proxy(IServices.class);
            ApiRequestModel api = new ApiRequestModel(11, "22", 0);
            Response response = service.putservice(api);
            ApiResponseModel apiResponse = response.readEntity(ApiResponseModel.class);
            System.out.println("API-JAVA>> " + "CNPJ: " + apiResponse.getCnpj() + " ADQ: " + apiResponse.getAdq() + " BLOCKCODE: " + apiResponse.getBlockcode());

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}
```

Init container

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Weld weld = new Weld();

        WeldContainer container = weld.initialize();

        container.select(ApiRequest.class).get().rest();

        container.shutdown();
    }
}
```

beans.xml  path: resources/META-INF/beans.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd">
</beans>
```

For this example: API Node.js + Express

index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const routes = require('./routes/customer.routes')

const app = express();

//Settings
app.set('appName', 'API for Java');
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 5000);

//Middlewares
app.use(morgan('combine'));
app.use(express.json())


// Routes
app.use('/api-java',routes);
app.get('/login', (req, res) => res.send('Hello desde login'))


// Start Server
app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
  console.log('Server running on port:', app.get('port'));
  console.log(app.get('appName'))
})
```

Routes

customer.routes.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('GET Response'))

router.put('/put', (req, res) => {
  const { adq, cnpj, blockcode } = req.body;

  console.log(req.body)
  res.json({
    adq : adq , cnpj, blockcode
  })
})

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Please add some context / text to the answer and reduce both the question and answer to the minimum for reproducing and solving.